# Atom causing Guard to run with every window change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, guard, atom-editor

I am running

- rails 4.1
- Guard (2.6.0)
- guard-livereload (2.1.2)
- rspec-rails (2.14.2)

I want guard to run, as expected - when a watched file has been modified and SAVED.
However, at present it runs far to often - when ever i change the focus on my window. (I am using Github's Atom). This does not happen when i switch back to textmate.  Is there something i can change in atom to stop it hitting these files and triggering guard on every simple change.

my guard file reads as follows.

```
guard "bundler" do
  watch("Gemfile")
end

guard :rspec, cmd: 'bundle exec rspec' do

    watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
    watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
    watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

 # Rails example
    watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
    watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
    watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
    watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
    watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
    watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

 # Capybara features specs
    watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

 # Turnip features and steps
    watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
    watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }

end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you have accidentally activated [autosave](https://github.com/atom/autosave).

- Open Settings `⌘,`
  [image]
- Digit autosave to filter the autosave settings 
  [image]
- Disable it by unchecking the `Enabled` checkbox

More informations ?

- [Open README]
  [image]

Comment: This was brilliant, thank you.So noob by me! Thank you, this was getting so frustrating.